# C# XAML: DisplayMemberBinding binding to object member

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a `CollectionViewSource` defined as `cvs` and I try to display in a `ListView`

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="FieldA" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FieldAStr}" Width="auto"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="FieldBMember1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FieldBObj.Member1}" Width="auto"/>

         </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The second property of each object in `csv` is an object itself, with a string property `Member1`, how can I bind this property, the way of binding in the above xaml code doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: Is `Member1` really a field? If yes then you cannot bind to fields. You need to convert it into public property

Comment: Did you try using DisplayMemberName?

Comment: @dkozl corrected the question, it is in fact a property.

Comment: What Xaml error is reported in the debug output when run under the debugger?

Comment: @OmegaMan actually it is just not displaying anything, no error. FieldA of course displayed correctly.

Comment: And `FieldBObj` is also a public property? Because you say "the second field of each object ...".

Comment: @Clemens yes, also a property

Comment: Have you checked the Output window for binding errors?

Comment: @tesla1060 generally what you're doing should work assuming both `FieldBObj` and `Member1` are public properties, these are exact names of these properties (it's case sensitive) and value either value is available at the time binding is evaluated or you implement `INPC` interface (applies to both `FieldBObj` and `Member1`). All binding errors should be displayed in Output window.